# Desarrollo de un "login" o "inicio de sesion" en Spring

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, spring-security

Estoy tratando de llevar a cabo un proyecto de una aplicacion web usando Spring y Thymeleaf. Resulta que la mayoria de secciones de mi app las tengo ya practicamente terminadas, pero aun me quede el que considero el paso mas importante, el login. Tengo un index.html (el principal) que es donde tengo el formulario con los campos de usuario y contraseña, pero por mas que me he informado y he visto tutoriales no consigo como llevarme los datos que se rellenen ahi a un controlador de java (por ej: UsuarioController) y que este se encargue de verificarme que dichas credenciales pertencen a algun usuario de mi base de datos. Junto con la ayuda de ChatGPT obtuve esto (aunque no funciona):

El contenido de index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Iniciosesion</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-image: url('/img/pexels-leon-ardho-1552242.jpg');
            background-size: cover;
            color: white;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            min-height: 100vh;
        }
        #form-container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="form-container">
    <h1>Iniciar Sesión</h1>
    <span th:if="${mensajeError != null}" style="color: red;">[[${mensajeError}]]</span>
    <form action="/index" method="post">
        <label for="usuario">Usuario</label>
        <input type="text" id="usuario" name="usuario" required>
        <br>
        <label for="contrasena">Contraseña:</label>
        <input type="password" id="contrasena" name="contrasena" required>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Iniciar Sesión">
        <input type="reset" value="Limpiar">
    </form>
</div>
<a th:href="@{inicio}"><input onClick="#" type="button" value="ir" name="boton" style="BORDER: rgb(128,128,128) 1px solid; FONT-SIZE: 18pt; FONT-FAMILY:Times New Roman;
         BACKGROUND-COLOR: rgb(229,233,233)"></a>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

y la funcion de "UsuarioController":

```js
    @PostMapping("index")
    public String loginUsuario (@RequestParam String usuario, @RequestParam String contrasena, HttpSession session) {
        Usuario user = usuarioService.getByUsuario(usuario);

        if (user == null || !user.getContraseña().equals(contrasena)) {
            // Si las credenciales son incorrectas, se muestra un mensaje de error y se redirige a la página de inicio de sesión.
            session.setAttribute("mensajeError", "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos.");
            return "redirect:/index";
        } else {
            // Si las credenciales son correctas, se establece una sesión y se redirige a la página principal.
            session.setAttribute("usuario", user);
            return "redirect:/inicio/index";
        }
    }
```

Por si tambien sirve de ayuda, este es el error que se muestra cuando introduzco los datos en el formulario y pulso en el boton de iniciar sesion:

[image: error]

Comment: ¿Cual es tu path al que se intenta acceder ?, veo /index y index en el controllador.
Sería bueno revisar que tus uri este correcta.

Comment: añadele "/" al postmaping en el metodo loginUsuario, ademas si tu controlador tiene una ruta tienes que añadirsela al form del inicio